# Find the value of the infinite series: $(1/3^2)+(1/3^3)+(1/3^4)+...+(1/5^2)+(1/5^3)+...+(1/7^2)+(1/7^3)+...+...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

Essentially the summation of all the reciprocals of odd numbers and their integer powers(starting from 2).  A close approximation could be {$1-\ln(2)$}.

My working was:

Consider the series $1/2^2+1/2^3+....+ 1/3^2+1/3^3+....$(for all integers).

I can segment each row as an infinite gp. First one being equal to $1/2=1/1*2$ $Second=1/6=1/2*3, third=1/12=1/3*4.....$

$Assume f(x)=x^2/2*1+x^3/2*3+..... $

$df(x)/d(x)=x+x^2/2+x^3/3...$ Which is $-ln(1-x)-x$

So $f(x)$=integral of $-x-ln(1-x)=ln(1-x)(1-x)+x-x^2/2+C$
$f(-1)=2ln2-3/2+C$=even gps positive and odd negative

$f(1)$= original series$=1/2+C$

$(f(1)-f(-1))/2=({(1/3^2)+(1/3^3)+(1/3^4)+...}+{(1/5^2)+(1/5^3)+....}+{...}+..)={1-ln(2)}??$

I'm not sure about this though

Also find the value of $(1/2^2)+(1/2^3)+(1/2^4)+...+(1/4^2)+(1/4^3)+...+(1/6^2)+(1/6^3)+...+...$

Comment: I do have a method of solving the question which resulted in the 1-ln(2) result, however I'm very new to mathematics and unsure about the result. Please attempt the problem and prove or disprove the result

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please show your working that you used to conclude the result. This way people may be more motivated to answer your question.

Comment: It'll be very hard to properly translate my working in this text box but I'll try. 
Assume the series 1/2^2+1/2^3+....+
1/3^2+1/3^3+....(for all integers). 
I can segment each row as an infinite gp. First one being equal to 1/2=1/1*2
Second=1/6=1/2*3, third=1/12=1/3*4.....
Assume f(x)=x^2/2*1+x^3/2*3+.....
df(x)/d(x)=x+x^2/2+x^3/3... Which is -ln(1-x)-x
So f(x)=integral of -x-ln(1-x)==ln(1-x)(1-x)+x-x^2/2+C
f(-1)=2ln2-3/2+C=even gps positive and odd negative
f(1)= original series=1/2+C
(f(1)-f(-1))/2=({(1/3^2)+(1/3^3)+(1/3^4)+......}+{(1/5^2)+(1/5^3)+....}+...}+..)=1-ln(2)????

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's difficult to show your work in a comment box, because the work should be in the main text of the question instead. You can put it there by editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: The problem can be reduced to the following:

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k-2)}$$ by using the summation of geometric progressions to infinite terms.

HINT 2:

You can work out from the previous hint that the summation is equal to: (try using partial fraction decomposition)

$$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k}= 1-ln(2)$$

Problem 2: You can again follow the same steps as earlier to obtain that the summation is:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k-1)(2k)} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} = ln(2)$$

Comment: Thank you. Could you evaluate the answer for the expression $(1/2^2)+(1/2^3)+(1/2^4)+...+(1/4^2)+(1/4^3)+...+(1/6^2)+(1/6^3)+...+...$?
Also adding these two expressions would result in the summation of reimann zeta functions 2,3,4.... right??(Except the first term$(1/1^s)$)

Comment: Yes you are right, and that equals 1.

Comment: Ohhhk thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 2):

For $n\ge 1$, we have a geometric series
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)^k}=\frac{\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}}{1-\frac{1}{2n+1}}=\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2-(2n+1)}=\frac{1}{4n^2+2n}.$$
Taking the sum over $n\ge 1$ gives
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{4n^2+2n}.$$
Now use partial fraction decomposition to rewrite $\frac{1}{4n^2+2n}$ and you will find that the above sum is (almost) a *familiar* series.

Comment: Thank you. Could you evaluate the answer for the expression $(1/2^2)+(1/2^3)+(1/2^4)+...+(1/4^2)+(1/4^3)+...+(1/6^2)+(1/6^3)+...+...$? It does converge right?
And adding these two expressions would result in the summation of reimann zeta functions 2,3,4,5,6.... right??(Except the first term$(1/1^s)$)

Comment: @Lithium so the first sum is $1-\ln 2$, and the same process shows the second sum you mentioned is $\ln 2$. You might as well not split up the even and odd cases though. You have $\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^3}+\cdots=\frac{1}{n(n-1)}=\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}$, etc.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying :)